# Python regex to get sentence before and after full stop

Tags: python, regex

i want to find various groups of strings based on period(full-stop) as a delimiter.
My sentences can be anything like:

1. "**balloon). It has too be**" => my regex should give groups:
   "balloon)." and "It has too be"
2. "**beautiful. Do it**" => my regex should give groups: "beautiful." and "Do it"
3. "**strong and large.**" => my regex should give groups: "strong and large."
   So to say the regex should return both the sentences before and after .
   I have tried many combinations of regex no regex is able to capture all the examples. Kindly help.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: Why not just use `str.split('.')`?

Comment: Better yet: use `nltk` altogether!

Comment: Thanks for the options. My string may have no period or it may also have $10.4. I do not want incorrect groups like 10 and 4 seperately. I have tried pattern : "((\S*\.)(\s[A-Z]+)*)" and "((.*)\.([\s\w*])" but nothing works

Answer (score 2):

You can split on a space and check for a period behind the space:

```
import re

s = ["balloon). It has too be", "beautiful. Do it", "strong and large." ]
final_data = [re.split("(?<=\.)\s", i) for i in s]
```

Final output:

```
[['balloon).', 'It has too be'], ['beautiful.', 'Do it'], ['strong and large.']]
```

Comment: If I have a sentence like this: `image.jpg`, how do I split it before and after the "." ?? So that I can get two strings, the `image` and the `jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use pattern frequently then use compile for faster process and use generator if your data contains large elements.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\.)\s")

data = ["balloon). It has too be", "beautiful. Do it", "strong and large." ]
final_op = (re.split(pattern, d) for d in data)
print list(final_op)
```